# git dependency hell? -- submodule pull failing

Tags: git

What am I doing wrong here?

```
$ git submodule foreach git pull # fails
$ cd Submodules/MBProgressHUD/
$ git diff
$ git checkout master
$ git pull
$ cd ..
$ cd ..
$ git submodule foreach git pull # fails
$ cd Submodules/ShareKit/
$ ls
$ git pull master
$ git checkout master
$ git diff
$ git submodule foreach git pull # fails
$ git status
$ git fetch
$ git pull
$ git submodule foreach git pull # fails
```

The last one is shown, but basically they all look like this:

```
Entering 'Submodules/JSONKit'
You are not currently on a branch. Please specify which
branch you want to merge with. See git-pull(1) for details.

    git pull <remote> <branch>

Stopping at 'Submodules/JSONKit'; script returned non-zero status.
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Submodules are downloaded with the `git submodule init` and `git submodule update` commands, not with git pull. See http://git-scm.com/book/en/Git-Tools-Submodules#Cloning-a-Project-with-Submodules for more info.